# Disable Launchd based daemon sudden termination upon shutdown

Tags: launchd, shutdown, plist, daemons

I'm running my own daemon under macOS Sierra and High-Sierra, and get unexpected behavior upon shutdown. according to the manual of [daemon life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Lifecycle.html), it says that ...

> If the system is being shut down or restarted, it sends a SIGTERM signal to all daemons, followed a few seconds later by SIGKILL signal.

However, in my case I see that my daemon only gets SIGKILL from `launchd` (my signal handler callback function for SIGTERM isn't being called)

I've verified that I doesn't allow sudden termination by setting the following fields in plist :

```
<key>NSSupportsSuddenTermination</key>
<false/>

<key>EnableTransactions</key>
<false/>
```

Any idea what am I missing here ?

Comment: See SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248907/launchdaemon-handling-system-shutdown-no-sigterm